# ClearAllBindings on ComboBox causes source updates

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I am writing a WPF application with a fairly large form, using WPF databinding.

I noticed that when I "let go" of form elements, they stay alive a lot longer than I want them to, which means they continue to get updates from the view, causing my application to slow down noticably. To prevent this, I recurse through the document and call `BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings()` on each element when a portion of the WPF tree gets released.

Now I run into the following issue. If my view contains a databound Combobox, like this:

```
 <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceItems}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

it can happen that the `ItemsSource` binding gets removed before the `SelectedValue` binding. As a result, the `SelectedItem` in my datamodel is set to `null`. That was not expected!

My question is: Is there a safe way to clear all databindings for a form without such side effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a typical MVVM application, setting the `DataContext` of the view to `null` will achieve what you want without the need for expensive and error-prone recursion through the visual tree. This is because the `DataContext` is inherited, and all bindings would typically be made against the `DataContext`.

Comment: Keep in mind that this may cause events to be triggered unwanted. For instance I had this issue with SelectionChanged events that were fired when the DataContext is set to null